# How to validate phone number in bot framework?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I'm using following code to get user input for a phone number. I want to validate user input and if it is incorrect, need to ask the user to enter again.

```
[function (session, results, next) {
    builder.Prompts.text(session, 'I will also need to know your contact number.');
}
,function (session, results, next) {
    session.userData.contactNo = results.response;
    next();
}]
```

I tried [this example](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/capability-SimpleTaskAutomation), but it gives a warning saying it is deprecated. Appreciate any help regarding the correct way to do this(without using the deprecated method). My phone number regex is `^[689]\d{3}\s?\d{4}$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an interesting sample in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-replace?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#create-custom-prompts-to-validate-input):

```
bot.dialog('/phonePrompt', [
    function (session, args) {
        if (args && args.reprompt) {
            builder.Prompts.text(session, "Enter the number using a format of either: '(555) 123-4567' or '555-123-4567' or '5551234567'")
        } else {
            builder.Prompts.text(session, "What's your phone number?");
        }
    },
    function (session, results) {
        var matched = results.response.match(/\d+/g);
        var number = matched ? matched.join('') : '';
        if (number.length == 10 || number.length == 11) {
            session.endDialogWithResult({ response: number });
        } else {
            session.replaceDialog('/phonePrompt', { reprompt: true });
        }
    }
]);
```

Here you can see that in the function handling the result, they are performing some checks and then if not valid they are doing a `replaceDialog` with a `reprompt` parameter.

You may try the same here with your business logic (ie: doing your regex check instead of the number length check in the sample)